# custom setter method for shared nsdateformatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

i am trying to create a custom setter method for a nsdateformatter. I am not sure whether this is leak free and optimized. is the memory management done properly. I am seeing a leak here. I don't know why . . .

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateFormatter   *customDateFormatter;
    ...
    @synthesize customDateFormatter; 
    ..
    - (NSDateFormatter *)customDateFormatter
    {
        if (customDateFormatter == nil)
        {
            [self setCustomDateFormatter:[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]];//it leaks here :(
            [self.customDateFormatter setLocale: self.locale];
            [self.customDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm:ss"];
        }
        return self.customDateFormatter;
    }
-(void) dealloc
{
     [customerDateFormatter release];    
     self.customDateFormatter = nil;
     [super dealloc];    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra retain.  Since your setter retains, and the alloc is a +1.  Here's the remedy:

```
  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]];  // 0+1=1
  [self setCustomDateFormatter:df];                       // 1+1=2
  [df release];                                           // 2-1=1
  // then in your dealloc 1-1=0
```

Comment: awesome . .this did not hit me at all :D

Comment: [self setCustomDateFormatter:df]; will it add 1 count ? . how ? . .just by accessing it increase the retain count ?

Comment: Yes.   You don't see it because it's in the @synthesized code.  The property is declared as "retain" which tells the setter to release the old value and retain the new one.

Comment: so all @synthesize code do this by default ? . . is there a way to see the (at)synthesize implementation for any instance variable ?

Comment: any @synthesize with "retain".  there's also a "copy" qualifier that will increase retain count.  if you don't want +1 retain count, or if the property is a scalar, like an int or something, then you use "assign".  Somewhere in the apple docs they show you what the different qualifiers generate.  I'll dig around a post a link if I find it.  On the idea of seeing the synthesized code for your particular properties, that's a good question.  I'll bet there's a way, but I don't know.  Maybe ask a new SO question on that?

Comment: You can't see the `@synthesized` code.  Not all `@synthesized` does it - it depends on your `@property` declaration.  If you used (assign) instead of (retain) it wouldn't, well, *retain* your object.

Comment: This is close (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).  Can't seem to find the one that actually illustrates the internals of the synthesized methods.  Maybe I just imagined it.

Answer (score 1):

Common mistake: you are using a setter for a retained property (i.e. "@property (retain)"), but you are retaining it yourself.  Thus it is being retained twice.

Just autorelease your custom formatter before setting the property, or don't use the setter (i.e. use the backing ivar directly).

Comment: whoops.  saw this just as i posted.  agree with @Conrad

Comment: ivar is the best solution to solve this ? do you think custom setter is mess or a it is a good one to practice ?

Comment: most of the times i am afraid of autoreleases . . i dont know how safe it is to use or i dont know how to make decisions on whether to use it  here or not . . i avoid using autos .

Comment: I see you already accepted @danh 's equally correct response, but you just need to know that "autorelease" behaves as does release, but effectively defers the actual release until the next turn of the run loop.  In practice, this means that autoreleased objects will survive at least the current function.  As far as reference counting goes, release and autorelease function identically.

Comment: so here is my question. i have a xml parser, i pulled all values and placed it in a data object with dictionaries, and i allocated all of them the same way . @property (retain . .0+1 . . alloc init . .1+1 . .and i am not sure whether to put a autorelease for previous line and put a release & nil @ dealloc method . . i know i am sounding pretty strange . but i am not sure whether this data object stays throughout the end of the app life cycle :(

Comment: I can't really follow what you are asking... can you open a new question and write out formatted code?  Post a link back here for me to take a look.